# What is page object modelling? and Why is it so important?

Tags: automated-testing, page-objects

I have been hearing a lot about page object modelling? Why is it so important?

Can someone please outline me page object model?

I'm currently working as QE in webservices area

Comment: You can find additional info in my answer to this post: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3798/good-resources-tutorials-tips-for-beginner-doing-automation/3804#3804

Comment: This gives a good insight on the topic: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects.  Also there are quite a few articles on the topic online, so is there anything specific you are looking for or just a general idea of people's view?

Answer (score 5):

Read [this](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.html) ( scroll down to the page objects section though the whole page us good ) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) for some background

Or from [this page](http://watirmelon.com/2012/06/04/roll-your-own-page-objects/)

> Taking it back to basics, essentially there are three functions I see
>   a page object pattern provides:
>
> Ability to easily instantiate pages in a consistent manner
>
> Ability to concisely describe elements on a page, keep it DRY by
>   avoiding repetition of element identifiers (using the underlying
>   driver’s API)
>
> Ability to provide higher level methods that use the elements to
>   perform user oriented functions.

and a tutorial [here](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/page-object-pattern.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Your question hints at a couple of questions:

**What Is a Page Object?**

A page object is code written to model an actual page (or part of a page) in a web application. Eg. each page in your app, would have an associated page object file that provides the “services” that the actual page offers. Eg. if there’s a button on a page in your application, you would have a reference to that button in your page object. If you then write a test that clicks that button, you would access the button through the page object.

**Why Use Page Objects?**

Page object provide many benefits, including:

1. Make tests more readable/easier to understand
2. Make tests easier to maintain
3. Help organize code into logical chunks

**How To Use Page Objects**

I have an example of the page object pattern I use in Sahi, written in Javascript [on my blog](http://qualityshepherd.com/2013/10/using-page-objects-in-sahi-javascript/). It walks through the included, working source code, which might help solidify the concept.

Answer (score 0):

#### A Page Object approach can be thought of as giving and using names for commonly used pieces of HTML pages.

For example if you identify a button in three places this way:

```
find('button#primary_driver_stage1')
...
click('button#primary_driver_stage1')
...
click('button#primary_driver_stage1')
```

There are now three problems:

1. It's hard to read
2. It repeats some element/attributes that might change
3. Any updates would have to be done in 3 places.

A Page Object approach solved this by giving the HTML DOM identifying elements/attributes a name, for example

```
primary_driver_stage1='button#primary_driver_stage1'
```

Then this is used in the code, e.g.

```
find(primary_driver_stage1)
...
click(primary_driver_stage1)
...
click(primary_driver_stage1)
```

and when it needs to updated for example to be a div instead of a button you can just update

```
primary_driver_stage1='div#primary_driver_stage1'
```

Store these defintions in one place and include them in the test spec and then the spec doesn't need to change when the page does.