# How to resolve Null pointer Exception?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, page-objects, exception

**Class 1: Logintest:**

```
import Utility.BrowserFactory;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

public class Logintest1 {
    BrowserFactory b=new BrowserFactory();
    public WebDriver driver;
  @Test
  public void f() {
      Loginpom lpom = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Loginpom.class);
      b.browserwait();
      lpom.obj();

  }
  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod()throws Exception {

      b.browser("chrome","https://www.gmail.com");
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod()throws Exception {
      b.browserwait();
      b.closebrowser();
  }

}
```

**Class 2: BrowserFactory:**

```
package Utility;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class BrowserFactory  {
public WebDriver driver;
Screenshots s=new Screenshots();

public WebDriver browser(String browsername, String url) throws IOException {
    if(browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Software\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
        //s.takescreenshot(driver,"E://eclipse projects//GmailSuite//Test Output//Login_Output//browserinitiation.jpeg");
    }
    else if(browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox") ) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver","E:\\Software\\driver\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    s.takescreenshot(driver, "E://eclipse projects//GmailSuite//Test Output//Login_Output//browserinitiation.jpeg");
driver.get(url);    
s.takescreenshot(driver, "E://eclipse projects//GmailSuite//Test Output//Login_Output//url_loading.jpeg");
driver.manage().window().maximize();    
return driver;
}

public void closebrowser() throws IOException {
    driver.quit();
    s.takescreenshot(driver, "E://eclipse projects//GmailSuite//Test Output//Login_Output//browserclosed.jpeg");
}

public void browserwait() {
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
}
```

**Class loginPage:**

```
package GmailTests;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class Loginpom {
public WebDriver driver;
public Loginpom(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver=driver;

}
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, xpath="//*[@type='email']") WebElement emails;
    @FindBy(id="identifierNext")WebElement nbutton;
    @FindBy(name="password")WebElement pw;
    @FindBy(id="passwordNext")WebElement pwnbutton;
public void obj() { 
    emails.sendKeys("sbhuvani661");
    nbutton.click();
    pw.sendKeys("abc");
    pwnbutton.click();
}

}
```

**Class Screenshot:**

```
package Utility;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


public class Screenshots {

//public WebDriver driver;
public void takescreenshot(WebDriver driver,String path)throws IOException {

    File sourcefilename = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(sourcefilename, new File("path"));

}
}
```

**Exception:**
The above method returns-

```
java.lang.NullpointerException at org.Selenium.support.PageFactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElemen
tLocator.java:69) at the line emails.sendKeys("sbhuvani661"); 
and lpom.obj();
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to instantiate elements of your page.

```
PageFactory.initElements(...)
```

Refer to this question to get the details: [How to Implement Page Object and Page Factory Pattern in Selenium Webdriver?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/how-to-implement-page-object-and-page-factory-pattern-in-selenium-webdriver). Since your fields are not instantiated, they are not deployed in memory, so when you are trying to access method of not existing object in

```
emails.sendKeys("sbhuvani661");
```

you get `NullPointerException`

Comment: Page factory was initiated in the class Logintest itself. Even though i tried initiating it as a constructor in the pom class but still the null pointer exception is throwing

Comment: When you initiate elements you pass the driver that is null.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it is null because it is not successfully finding the element in question. Look to make sure that your @FindBy annotation is correct for WebElement emails.

Comment: WebElement is represented correctly