# java.lang.NullPointerException problem in Selenium Test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation, page-objects, junit

I'm learning Selenium POM with Junit and ran into a problem.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at MainPage.clickSignIn(MainPage.java:27)
at MainPageTest.signInTest(MainPageTest.java:28)
```

**My class:**

```
public class MainPage {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public MainPage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "a[@class='HeaderMenu-link no-underline mr-3']")
    private WebElement signInBtn;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[@class='HeaderMenu-link d-inline-block no-underline border border-gray-dark rounded-1 px-2 py-1']")
    private WebElement signUpBtn;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='user[login]']")
    private WebElement userNameField;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='user[email]']")
    private WebElement userEmailField;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='user[password]']")
    private WebElement userPasswordField;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//button[text()='Sign up for GitHub'][1]")
    private WebElement signUpFormButton;

    public LoginPage clickSignIn(){
        signInBtn.click();
        return new LoginPage(driver);
    }

    public SignUpPage clickSignUp(){
        signUpBtn.click();
        return new SignUpPage(driver);
    }

    public SignUpPage clickSignUpForm(){
        signUpFormButton.click();
        return new SignUpPage(driver);
    }

    public MainPage typeUserName(String username){
        userNameField.sendKeys(username);
        return this;
    }

    public MainPage typeUserEmail(String userEmail){
        userEmailField.sendKeys(userEmail);
        return this;
    }

    public MainPage typeUserPassword(String userPassword){
        userPasswordField.sendKeys(userPassword);
        return this;
    }

    public SignUpPage register(String username, String userEmail, String userPassword){
        this.typeUserName(username);
        this.typeUserEmail(userEmail);
        this.typeUserPassword(userPassword);
        this.clickSignUpForm();
        return new SignUpPage(driver);
    }
}
```

**And my test class:**

```
public class MainPageTest {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private MainPage mainPage;
    private LoginPage loginPage;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Java projects\\pageobjectseleniumtest\\src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("https://github.com");
        mainPage = new MainPage(driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void signInTest(){
        LoginPage loginPage = mainPage.clickSignIn();
        String heading = loginPage.getHeadingText();
        Assert.assertEquals("Sign in to GitHub", heading);
    }
}
```

Help me, please.

Comment: I think this link will help you at this point.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236855/java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-running-a-testcase-via-selenium-webdriver-in/17237255

Comment: @Meet I have tried with _try/catch_ construction and my test passed, but wasn't click to **signIn** button. Maybe i don't understand smthg...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are forgeting to init the Elements and try to click on an element that is still null.

Add something like this to the constructor of the page

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
```

Something like:

```
public MainPage(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

Look at this question for an example: [How to Implement Page Object and Page Factory Pattern in Selenium Webdriver?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/how-to-implement-page-object-and-page-factory-pattern-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Thank you very much! You have helped me!

Answer (score 2):

Try to change

```
@FindBy(xpath = "a[@class='HeaderMenu-link no-underline mr-3']")
    private WebElement signInBtn;
```

to

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@class='HeaderMenu-link no-underline mr-3']")
    private WebElement signInBtn;
```

Two slashes are missing before `a`.

Comment: Thank you very much too! You have helped me, i'm blind...